# Google Api Java

Tags: java, google-docs

Выкидывает ошибку в DocumentList и не видит метод list() как можно пофиксить?

```
package io.proj3ct.SpringDemoBot.config;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.docs.v1.Docs;
import com.google.api.services.docs.v1.model.Document;
import com.google.api.services.docs.v1.model.DocumentList;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.List;

public class GoogleDocsService {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Docs API Example";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    protected Docs docsService;

    public GoogleDocsService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        docsService = new Docs.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, null)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public List<Document> getDocuments() throws IOException {
        return docsService.documents().list().execute().getDocuments();
    }

}
```